# Error en json ajax y codeigniter usando join

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, join

tengo una ventana modal que quiero que muestre la información del producto, pero la tabla de la base de datos tiene dos campos que guardan el id en lugar del nombre. Ejemplo la tabla productos

Código = 123456
Nombre = Producto 1
Categoría = 1 -> hay otra tabla categorías que contiene el id y el nombre
fabricante = 1 -> igual hay una tabla para fabricantes que contiene el id y nombre

no tengo ningún problema en que muestre la información tal cual esta en la tabla productos, pero muestra categoría=1 y fabricantes=1 y lo que quiero es que muestre los nombres del fabricante y la categoría, y cada vez que hago la consulta con join entre las tablas, me da un error de ajax.

esta es la función en el modelo que hace la búsqueda del producto

```
public function get_by_id($id)
{
$this->db->select("p.*,c.nombre as categoria, f.nombre as fabricante");
$this->db->from("productos p");
$this->db->join("categorias c","p.categoria_id = c.id");
$this->db->join("fabricantes f","p.fabricante_id = f.id");   
$this->db->where("id",$id);   
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();

}
```

este el controlador

```
public function producto_mostrar($id)
{
    $data = $this->productos->get_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

y este el codigo en ajax

```
  function mostrar_producto(id)
{

$('#form')[0].reset(); 
$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); 
$('.help-block').empty(); 



$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('almacen/productos/producto_mostrar')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
        $('#codigo').text(data.codigo);
        $('#nombre').text(data.nombre);
        $('#descripcion').text(data.descripcion);
        $('#precio').text(data.precio);
        $('#precio_compra').text(data.precio_compra);
        $('#stock').text(data.stock);
        $('#stock_minimo').text(data.stock_minimo);
        $('#categoria').text(data.categoria);
        $('#fabricante').text(data.fabricante);
        $('#modal_formm').modal('show'); /
        $('.modal-title').text('Producto'); 

        $('#photo-preview').show(); 




    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
 });
 }
```

si la función del modelo la uso así

```
 public function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

no da error pero muestra la información de la tabla productos tal cual esta con los id en lugar del nombre de categorías y fabricante.
Debo aclarar que esa consulta con join funciona bien si no utilizo json pero si la uso con json me da el error.

Answer (score 0):

El error del json es porque necesitas pasar un array al controlador y con row() no consigues ese efecto. prueba a cambiar esto:

```
$this->db->select("p.*,c.nombre as categoria, f.nombre as fabricante");
$this->db->from("productos p");
$this->db->join("categorias c","p.categoria_id = c.id");
$this->db->join("fabricantes f","p.fabricante_id = f.id");   
$this->db->where("id",$id);
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

También te recomiendo hacer un `console.log(data)` en el success del ajax para que puedas ver que te está devolviendo la consulta y así mirar como sacar los datos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, me sigue saliendo el mismo error, y en la consola me dice get 500(internal server error)

Comment: send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
mostrar_producto @ productos:774
onclick @ productos:1

Comment: Entonces es fallo de la consulta, intenta poner los nombres de las tablas sin alias, es decir, quita las "c" y "p" y pon los nombres "productos.* " y "categorias.* ". Y los mismo con los fabricantes

Comment: no se si lo estoy haciendo bien, lo coloque así pero sigue dando error          public function get_mostrar($id)
 {
  $this->db->select("productos.*,categorias.nombre as categoria, fabricantes.nombre as fabricante");
        $this->db->from("productos");
  $this->db->join("categorias","productos.categoria_id = id");
  $this->db->join("fabricantes","productos.fabricante_id = id");   
  $this->db->where("id",$id);
  return $this->db->get()->result();
  }